# Call to a member function _kohana_load_view() on a non-object in kohana

Tags: kohana, kohana-3.3

My same code is working in other online domain and localhost but on other on line domain its giving error in kohana.
I think its related to file permissions but im getting it.

Fatal error: Call to a member function _kohana_load_view() on a non-object in /home/wmvh/public_html/system/libraries/View.php on line 243

**EDIT**
Error is giving on this line of view.php
$output = Kohana::$instance->_kohana_load_view($this->kohana_filename, $data)

Comment: What is difference in server configuration between them? Does it work on Windows and not on Unix?

Comment: just the base url and db name , pwd are different rest is all the same